# R character set to data frame

Tags: r

I open the file with Scan, because I want delete some text. I get the following results:

```
[1] " Time   \t Speed  \t  HR    \tV'E     \t  BF    \t V'O2   \t V'CO2  \t  RER   \tVO2/kg  \t EqO2   \t EqCO2  \t Load   \t O2/HR  "
[2] "  00:05 \t  0.0   \t   101  \t    15  \t    27  \t   361  \t   417  \t 1.15   \t  5.7   \t 32.1   \t 27.8   \t     0  \t  3.6   "
[3] "  00:10 \t  0.0   \t   106  \t    18  \t    22  \t   440  \t   491  \t 1.12   \t  7.0   \t 36.0   \t 32.2   \t     0  \t  4.2   "
[4] "  00:15 \t  0.0   \t   109  \t    12  \t    12  \t   349  \t   361  \t 1.03   \t  5.5   \t 31.1   \t 30.1   \t     0  \t  3.2   "
[5] "  00:20 \t  0.0   \t   104  \t    20  \t    24  \t   575  \t   558  \t 0.97   \t  9.1   \t 29.4   \t 30.3   \t     0  \t  5.5   "
[6] "  00:25 \t  0.0   \t   105  \t    19  \t    22  \t   525  \t   523  \t 1.00   \t  8.3   \t 31.3   \t 31.4   \t     0  \t  5.0   "
[7] "  00:30 \t  0.0   \t    91  \t    14  \t    16  \t   394  \t   390  \t 0.99   \t  6.3   \t 30.2   \t 30.6   \t     0  \t  4.3   "
[8] "  00:35 \t  0.0   \t   100  \t    18  \t    21  \t   467  \t   465  \t 0.99   \t  7.4   \t 33.7   \t 33.9   \t     0  \t  4.7   "
[9] "  00:40 \t  0.0   \t   101  \t    17  \t    14  \t   490  \t   479  \t 0.98   \t  7.8   \t 30.8   \t 31.5   \t     0  \t  4.9   "
[10] "  00:45 \t  0.0   \t   111  \t    13  \t    15  \t   371  \t   357  \t 0.96   \t  5.9   \t 30.4   \t 31.5   \t     0  \t  3.3   "
[11] "  00:50 \t  0.0   \t    86  \t    11  \t    23  \t   329  \t   281  \t 0.85   \t  5.2   \t 26.5   \t 31.1   \t     0  \t  3.8   "
[12] "  00:55 \t  0.0   \t    85  \t    20  \t    20  \t   635  \t   566  \t 0.89   \t 10.1   \t 28.0   \t 31.4   \t     0  \t  7.5   "
[13] "  00:58 \t  0.0   \t    91  \t    13  \t    20  \t   386  \t   348  \t 0.90   \t  6.1   \t 29.1   \t 32.3   \t     0  \t  4.2   "
```

Now I want transform this data in a numeric data frame, Do you know any solution?.

Comment: Have you tried `read.table(text=txtvector, header=TRUE)`? (BTW: you should be able to do it directly without `scan`, but I don't know for certain without knowing more of your code and file structure.)

Comment: I have error with this senteces,datos= scan("prueba.csv",sep="\n",what="")
datos= datos[-c(1:10,12:13)], datos2= read.table(datos,header = TRUE). Original file is a csv file with headers and I don´t get read with R. Peso: 63,0 kg Altura: 181,0 cm
Edad: 14 a€os  
   
Deporte: Atletismo Especialidad:  Fondo- Mediofondo

Protocolo: CGTD_RAMPA21 Erg¢metro: Tap¡z
Fecha: 04/07/2012 Hora: 11:22:41

Comment: You forgot `text=`. Read `?read.table` to find out more.

Comment: I solution the problem . Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just do `read.table("prueba.csv", header = TRUE)` to read directly from the file?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

```
txt <- c(" Time   \t Speed  \t  HR    \tV'E     \t  BF    \t V'O2   \t V'CO2  \t  RER   \tVO2/kg  \t EqO2   \t EqCO2  \t Load   \t O2/HR  ", 
         "  00:05 \t  0.0   \t   101  \t    15  \t    27  \t   361  \t   417  \t 1.15   \t  5.7   \t 32.1   \t 27.8   \t     0  \t  3.6   ", 
         "  00:10 \t  0.0   \t   106  \t    18  \t    22  \t   440  \t   491  \t 1.12   \t  7.0   \t 36.0   \t 32.2   \t     0  \t  4.2   ", 
         "  00:15 \t  0.0   \t   109  \t    12  \t    12  \t   349  \t   361  \t 1.03   \t  5.5   \t 31.1   \t 30.1   \t     0  \t  3.2   ", 
         "  00:20 \t  0.0   \t   104  \t    20  \t    24  \t   575  \t   558  \t 0.97   \t  9.1   \t 29.4   \t 30.3   \t     0  \t  5.5   ", 
         "  00:25 \t  0.0   \t   105  \t    19  \t    22  \t   525  \t   523  \t 1.00   \t  8.3   \t 31.3   \t 31.4   \t     0  \t  5.0   ", 
         "  00:30 \t  0.0   \t    91  \t    14  \t    16  \t   394  \t   390  \t 0.99   \t  6.3   \t 30.2   \t 30.6   \t     0  \t  4.3   ", 
         "  00:35 \t  0.0   \t   100  \t    18  \t    21  \t   467  \t   465  \t 0.99   \t  7.4   \t 33.7   \t 33.9   \t     0  \t  4.7   ", 
         "  00:40 \t  0.0   \t   101  \t    17  \t    14  \t   490  \t   479  \t 0.98   \t  7.8   \t 30.8   \t 31.5   \t     0  \t  4.9   ", 
         "  00:45 \t  0.0   \t   111  \t    13  \t    15  \t   371  \t   357  \t 0.96   \t  5.9   \t 30.4   \t 31.5   \t     0  \t  3.3   ", 
         "  00:50 \t  0.0   \t    86  \t    11  \t    23  \t   329  \t   281  \t 0.85   \t  5.2   \t 26.5   \t 31.1   \t     0  \t  3.8   ", 
         "  00:55 \t  0.0   \t    85  \t    20  \t    20  \t   635  \t   566  \t 0.89   \t 10.1   \t 28.0   \t 31.4   \t     0  \t  7.5   ", 
         "  00:58 \t  0.0   \t    91  \t    13  \t    20  \t   386  \t   348  \t 0.90   \t  6.1   \t 29.1   \t 32.3   \t     0  \t  4.2   "
         )

dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 12 obs. of  13 variables:
#  $ Time  : chr  "00:05" "00:10" "00:15" "00:20" ...
#  $ Speed : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ HR    : int  101 106 109 104 105 91 100 101 111 86 ...
#  $ V.E   : int  15 18 12 20 19 14 18 17 13 11 ...
#  $ BF    : int  27 22 12 24 22 16 21 14 15 23 ...
#  $ V.O2  : int  361 440 349 575 525 394 467 490 371 329 ...
#  $ V.CO2 : int  417 491 361 558 523 390 465 479 357 281 ...
#  $ RER   : num  1.15 1.12 1.03 0.97 1 0.99 0.99 0.98 0.96 0.85 ...
#  $ VO2.kg: num  5.7 7 5.5 9.1 8.3 6.3 7.4 7.8 5.9 5.2 ...
#  $ EqO2  : num  32.1 36 31.1 29.4 31.3 30.2 33.7 30.8 30.4 26.5 ...
#  $ EqCO2 : num  27.8 32.2 30.1 30.3 31.4 30.6 33.9 31.5 31.5 31.1 ...
#  $ Load  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ O2.HR : num  3.6 4.2 3.2 5.5 5 4.3 4.7 4.9 3.3 3.8 ...
```